# Office.Interop.Publisher com outofmemoryexception when call via aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, com-interop

I am trying to run a catalog merge on a Microsoft Publisher document when a user clicks a button on a web page. It gets an OutOfMemoryException error message.  This code runs just fine in a console app.  So I am wondering if there is any tricks to get it to work.  I was able to do Word merge on a docx file this way, but Publisher seems to get the OutOfmemoryException immediately.

```
        protected void genStaffIndex_Bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataSource = @"C:\Users\score\Documents\My Data Sources\(local) caraway SupportStaffView.odc";
        string fileGenDir = Server.MapPath("~/HootAdmin/GenDocs");
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(fileGenDir, "SupportStaffCatalog.pub");

        string sourceDoc = Server.MapPath("~/HootAdmin/DocTemplates/SupportStaffCatalog.pub");
        long bytes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.Application();
        bytes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
        var mydoc = application.Open(sourceDoc, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.PbSaveOptions.pbDoNotSaveChanges);

        mydoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(bstrDataSource: dataSource);
        var newdoc = mydoc.MailMerge.Execute(false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.PbMailMergeDestination.pbMergeToNewPublication);
        mydoc.Close();
        newdoc.SaveAs(outputFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.PbFileFormat.pbFilePublication, false);
        newdoc.Close();
        application.Quit();
```

[image: Here is the exception in action]

Comment: Not an answer, but out of memory is a generic exception you get from some internal failure from COM objects. I used to get it from drawing outside the bounds of a GDI+ bitmap for example, even though it had nothing to do with memory.

Comment: Also, another thing to point out is that Office Interop is not recommended for use in a server, because it's not thread safe and consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes I agree. I just wanted to take someone's Publisher doc and run the merge for them via the web and download the resulting document to them.  I really didn't want to rewrite anything.  The thing that gets me is that in a console app it runs easily and is only 25meg, but under iis it becomes 256mb before the document load.